# C# Bitmap Lose Original Color after crossing the bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, colors, bitmap

This is the block of the code.

- Image came from azure storage.

> ```
> > public void ResizeImage(Image image, int blockWidth, int blockHeight)
> >                          { Bitmap xy = new Bitmap(image, image.Width, image.Height);  }
> ```

After just creating the object when I saved the image, It will lose the color of the image.(I have saved the image in all format png, jpg, tiff, bmp)
As I am able to fix the issue of the color by adding 
These code block after doing my stuff

```
foreach (System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem item in image.PropertyItems)
                        {
                            xy.SetPropertyItem(item);
                        }
```

(If this would fix then no needs to read the next lines of the Problem.)

it gave me image as i expected.
but again I have to perform the merge operation with the same image and when I use bitmap for merge, again image lose it's color,

I can use the above code again and added the color to it(It looks Good) but 
when I added second image, second image acquire the property of colors added on the first image and it's color change.

Can I get the solution, why bitmap doing so?

Comment: That `ResizeImage` method cannot be the code you are actually running. It doesn't do anything to the image, it doesn't even return the bitmap it is making. What gives?

Comment: Have you checked the _contents_ of these properties?